# Replace color of bars in plotly

Tags: r, colors, plotly, bar-chart

I want to change the colours of the bars in my barplot. Either by replacing the default orange and blue with other manual colours, or by using a palette.

```
library(plotly)
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(
  A = as.factor(c(0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)),
  B = as.factor(rep(c("aaa", "bbb"), 4)),
  C = c(10, 90, 15, 85, 2, 98, 19, 81)
)

plot_ly(
  data = df,
  x = ~ C,
  y = ~ A,
  type = "bar",
  split = ~ B
) %>%
  layout(barmode = "stack")
```

---------EDIT-----------
Just add color and colors parameter :

```
plot_ly(
  data = df,
  x = ~ C,
  y = ~ A,
  type = "bar",
  split = ~ B,
  color = ~B,
  colors = c("#fc6847", "#3cc7ed")
) %>%
  layout(barmode = "stack")**
```

Comment: You mean this: `plot_ly(
    data = df,
    x = ~C,
    y = ~A,
    type = "bar",
    split = ~B,
    color = ~B,
    colors = c("green", "blue")
  ) %>% layout(barmode = "stack")`